# What is inner cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models

From the book "Data Analysis and Data Mining" by Adelchi Azzalini and Bruno Scarpa, page 206:

> Such a low percentage and the small absolute value
>   suggest using cross-validation to trade off bias and variance. We
>   assessed the performance of different models by 10-fold
>   cross-validation, using the same random partition for all methods. To
>   compare the actually observed data, we predicted each of the 10 parts
>   using the best model fitted by using the other parts, thus avoiding
>   having to divide the data set into training and validation sets. We
>   typically also used **inner cross-validation** to choose a model within
>   each class.

What is inner cross validation?

Answer (score 2):

I think the authors just mean they did cross-validation to choose models within each fold of the first (outer) cross-validation. That's what I would usually call "nested cross-validation".

Answer (score 1):

On each of the 10 folds, there was a model selection performed separately, for example for feature selection. This cross-validation on the folds is then called inner crossvalidation. This has to be done to avoid a bias when using cross-validation to balance the model (like in this case).

For more information, see the wikipedia-entry on cross validation (especially chapter Limitations and misuse): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29